# Python: Choose function in command line argument

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

In a Python program (with more than one user defined functions), I **want to specify which function to use through command line arguments**. For e.g., I have the following functions, **func1()**, **func2()**, **func3()** in my Python program, and I am using the following technique presently:

```
python prog.py -func func2"
```

My program is something like this:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='')
parser.add_argument('-func', help='')
args = parser.parse_args()
func_type = globals()[args.func]()

def func1(): 
    print "something1"
def func2(): 
    print "something2"
def func3(): 
    print "something3"

func_type()
```

I get the following error:

```
KeyError: 'func2'
```

I will really appreciate if someone can tell me how I can implement the desired functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two simple mistakes related to `func_type = globals()[args.func]()`

1. The functions you are looking for have not been defined yet.  Move the function definitions above this line.
2. You are **calling** the function instead of saving a reference to it in variable `func_type`.

Comment: And also, like you said in an earlier edit, the functions need to be defined before they're looked up in globals. So in addition to removing the parentheses, @SiddTheKid should move all three function declarations above the argument parsing block.

Comment: Adding that back.  :)  Thanks @galenlong.